# How to deploy Havana with juju

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, openstack

I've been all over the web searching for an installation guide for openstack **Havana** via **juju** charms over Ubuntu **saucy** 13.10 *which is said to be build specially for Havana;* with no luck at all.

All I could find is either how to install the ancient openstack **Essax** over **Precise** 12.04 or installing **Havana** over 12.04 directly *"without **juju**"*.

I tried blindly by deploying these charms over 10 MaaS nodes, and add all the possible relations between then from the gui:

- juju-gui
- openstack-dashboard
- cinder
- glance
- keystone
- nova-cloud-controller
- quantum-gateway
- mysql
- rabbitmq-server
- nova-compute

And all were deployed and started successfully. Yet I couldn't browse to horizon.

I also tried to follow [openstack docs of 12.04](http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_preface.html), but since all the charms are already pre-configured I founded duplicate configs and keys that made the thing worst.

> Could you please give me any reference or guide me to how to start.
>
> > Thank you.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but did you expose horizon? If not, you won't be able to access it. Also, can you post the output of "juju status" from the command line?

Comment: Yes I had exposed it.
I cannot post the juju stat output because I gave up and demoted the lab :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up and demoted the whole lab and rolled back to 12.04 because it turns out that it cannot be done.

I kept getting the error: **cloud-archive only supported on precise**

Comment: Unfortunately the pocket cloud for cloud-archive is only designed for LTS releases. Canonical is committed to providing the best OpenStack experience for LTS releases so Havana will build just fine on precise with both Juju charms and out of the box manual setups